# Plugin for Redmine to appear only in certain project menus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I got my Redmine (v2.0.3) working. It now shows in the project menu of every project but I can't figure out how to only activate it for selected projects. E.g. only for projects that have a project custom field set to a specific value. I got the custom field created and figured out where the data is stored. But how do I tell Redmine when to or not to show the plugin in the project menu?

I did come across the possibility to use :if to specify a proc but the proc doesn't allow me to call a method of one of my plugins created models. 
E.g. I created a model called Param and I want to call the method Param.check_to_display.
But shows the error message

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'check_to_display' for Param(....):Class)
```

My init.rb says:

```
menu :project_menu, :info, {:controller=>'info', :action=>'index'}, :caption=>'Ticker', :after=>:activity, :param=>:project_id, :if=>Proc.new{||Param.check_to_display()}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How embarrassing, a simple mistake. I defined the method check_to_display as follows:

```
def check_to_display
```

obviously it should have been

```
def self.check_to_display
```

And for those who are interested in the total code:

```
class Param < ActiveRecord::Base
  unloadable

  def self.check_to_display(p)
    cf = CustomField.where("type='ProjectCustomField' and name='THE_FLAG'").first
    return false if cf.nil?
    return false if p.nil?
    cv = CustomValue.where("customized_type='Project' and customized_id=? and custom_field_id=?",p.id,cf.id).first
    return false if cv.nil?
    return false if cv.value.nil?
    cv.value.strip!
    return cv.value != ""
  end
end
```

and not to forget, init.rb should look as follows:

```
menu :project_menu, :info, {:controller=>'info', :action=>'index'}, :caption=>'Ticker', :after=>:activity, :param=>:project_id, :if=>Proc.new{|p|Param.check_to_display(p)}
```